# Install Ubuntu 20 side by side with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I have a new computer with windows 10. I want to install LTS of Ubuntu 20, side by side with.
Is Ubuntu 20 allow this technique or not and it should me to use Ubuntu only?

Note: I know that I well disable UEFI. But, I catch an information said: Ubuntu 18 and down it allowed to be side by side with windows, than Ubuntu 20 it is not allowing, is that correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Ubuntu has products with *year* format (e.g Ubuntu Core 18, Ubuntu Core 20) which are *snap* only and intended for appliances, devices or cloud use.  Ubuntu also has it's main products which use the *year.month* format and are *deb* packaged based, but can also use *snap* packages. They are different products, and it sounds like you want a 20.04 product which is available for desktops, and not an appliance/server or *headless* product like Ubuntu Core 20.  I'd suggest using official tutorials https://ubuntu.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a tutorial how to install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10: https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/ . I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a computer with preinstalled Windows 10 and can confirm that it is possible (however I did that on a computer without UEFI). The most important thing is to shrink the Windows partition to make some unallocated space on the disk where Ubuntu will be installed. The installer will take care of the rest.